# How to Convert date to time in amchart v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

i just want to display "6 AM" or just time only in my X AXIS, instead of showing `2019-09-05 06:00:00`

Here is my sample 
https://jsfiddle.net/uwtz3p4h/

is there any chance that is it possible to display time only? i cant find anything in their sample in their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the `categoryAxis.labelFunction` parameter to format the labels. You can provide a function to this parameter which accepts the value of the label as a string, which you can then parse to a `Date` object and format as required:

```
"labelFunction": function(valueText, serialDataItem, categoryAxis) {
  // '06:00' format
  var date = new Date(valueText);
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var mins = date.getMinutes();
  return ('00' + hours).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + mins).slice(-2);

  // '6AM' format:
  var hours = new Date(valueText).getHours();
  return hours + (hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM');
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/3dra8z6p/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Here i added one function

```
function converttoTime(t){
   var d=new Date(t);
   return d.getHours() +":"+d.getMinutes()+d.getSeconds()
}
```

I have modified your fiddle you can look into it
here is working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/Lah39yfm/4/)